# Grafana build docker image in MACOS?

Tags: css, docker, grafana, docker-build

I've made changes to grafana source code.
Ran e2e tests to make sure its working.
I work on MACOS

But when I tried to build a docker image from this, am afraid I don't understand how this works.

- Ran this command  make build-docker-full

output:

```
make build-docker-full
build docker container
docker build --tag grafana/grafana:dev .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  1.465GB
Step 1/44 : FROM golang:1.13.4-alpine
 ---> 3024b4e742b0
Step 2/44 : RUN apk add --no-cache gcc g++
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 0a34470e75af
Step 3/44 : WORKDIR $GOPATH/src/github.com/grafana/grafana
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 746e9a262b17
Step 4/44 : COPY go.mod go.sum ./
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 991f5eb4e93c
Step 5/44 : COPY vendor vendor
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 31461560264e
Step 6/44 : RUN go mod verify
 ---> Using cache
 ---> fb1ca8327171
Step 7/44 : COPY pkg pkg
 ---> 3766271f9d5a
Step 8/44 : COPY build.go package.json ./
 ---> 11ebcd1d9457
Step 9/44 : RUN go run build.go build
 ---> Running in aff10ee85d73
Version: 7.0.0-pre, Linux Version: 7.0.0, Package Iteration: 1584810976pre
rm -r ./bin/linux-amd64/grafana-server
rm -r ./bin/linux-amd64/grafana-server.md5
go version
go version go1.13.4 linux/amd64
Targeting linux/amd64
go build -ldflags -w -X main.version=7.0.0-pre -X main.commit=unknown-dev -X main.buildstamp=1584810976 -X main.buildBranch=master -mod=vendor -o ./bin/linux-amd64/grafana-server ./pkg/cmd/grafana-server
rm -r ./bin/linux-amd64/grafana-cli
rm -r ./bin/linux-amd64/grafana-cli.md5
go version
go version go1.13.4 linux/amd64
Targeting linux/amd64
go build -ldflags -w -X main.version=7.0.0-pre -X main.commit=unknown-dev -X main.buildstamp=1584811210 -X main.buildBranch=master -mod=vendor -o ./bin/linux-amd64/grafana-cli ./pkg/cmd/grafana-cli
Removing intermediate container aff10ee85d73
 ---> dd409b765652
Step 10/44 : FROM node:12.13.0-alpine
 ---> 69c8cc9212ec
Step 11/44 : RUN apk add --no-cache curl &&    cd /tmp && curl -Ls https://github.com/dustinblackman/phantomized/releases/download/2.1.1/dockerized-phantomjs.tar.gz | tar xz &&    cp -R lib lib64 / &&    cp -R usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu /usr/lib &&    cp -R usr/share /usr/share &&    cp -R etc/fonts /etc &&    curl -k -Ls https://bitbucket.org/ariya/phantomjs/downloads/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2 | tar -jxf - &&    cp phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64/bin/phantomjs /usr/local/bin/phantomjs
 ---> Using cache
 ---> f6e3c1365333
Step 12/44 : WORKDIR /usr/src/app/
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 68d834461a97
Step 13/44 : COPY package.json yarn.lock ./
 ---> d7e624ffddc4
Step 14/44 : COPY packages packages
 ---> dae5b06d3315
Step 15/44 : RUN yarn install --pure-lockfile --no-progress
 ---> Running in 0b6acb809b2e
yarn install v1.19.1
[1/5] Validating package.json...
[2/5] Resolving packages...
[3/5] Fetching packages...
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
info fsevents@1.2.9: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.2.9" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info fsevents@2.1.2: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@2.1.2" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
[4/5] Linking dependencies...
warning "@grafana/slate-react > slate-react-placeholder@0.2.8" has unmet peer dependency "slate-react@>=0.22.0".
warning "workspace-aggregator-08c343d0-af45-4bd4-81c2-559647a82d7d > @grafana/data > rollup-plugin-visualizer@0.9.2" has incorrect peer dependency "rollup@>=0.60.0 <1".
warning "workspace-aggregator-08c343d0-af45-4bd4-81c2-559647a82d7d > @grafana/ui > @storybook/addon-docs@5.3.9" has unmet peer dependency "react-is@^16.8.0".
warning "workspace-aggregator-08c343d0-af45-4bd4-81c2-559647a82d7d > @grafana/ui > @storybook/addon-storysource@5.3.14" has unmet peer dependency "@storybook/source-loader@*".
warning "workspace-aggregator-08c343d0-af45-4bd4-81c2-559647a82d7d > @grafana/ui > storybook-dark-mode@0.3.0" has unmet peer dependency "@storybook/api@>= 5.x".
warning "workspace-aggregator-08c343d0-af45-4bd4-81c2-559647a82d7d > @grafana/ui > storybook-dark-mode@0.3.0" has unmet peer dependency "@storybook/addons@>= 5.x".
warning "workspace-aggregator-08c343d0-af45-4bd4-81c2-559647a82d7d > @grafana/ui > storybook-dark-mode@0.3.0" has unmet peer dependency "@storybook/components@>= 5.x".
warning "workspace-aggregator-08c343d0-af45-4bd4-81c2-559647a82d7d > @grafana/ui > storybook-dark-mode@0.3.0" has unmet peer dependency "@storybook/core-events@>= 5.x".
warning "workspace-aggregator-08c343d0-af45-4bd4-81c2-559647a82d7d > @grafana/ui > @storybook/addon-docs > @egoist/vue-to-react@1.1.0" has unmet peer dependency "vue@^2.6.10".
warning "workspace-aggregator-08c343d0-af45-4bd4-81c2-559647a82d7d > @grafana/ui > @storybook/addon-actions > react-inspector > storybook-chromatic@2.2.2" has unmet peer dependency "@storybook/core@3.* || 4.* || 5.*".
[5/5] Building fresh packages...
Done in 1729.76s.
```

And I left this overnight;

The process didn't finish, so I interrupted.

```
^Cmake: *** [build-docker-full] Interrupt: 2
```

Can any one help me build this.??
I want to know, where the image is built and how I could pull this image.

My current guess is it will directly push this image to my dockerhub repo as grafana:dev.

Thank you.

Comment: You could try building it in a linux environment rather than osx (which despite the protestations of the unwashed masses, is as problematic with docker as windows-10). If you don't have one you could either get a low-powered ec2 instance running ubuntu or amazon linux, or you could just make a build container based on ubuntu with build-tools and docker installed, then run that while mounting the docker socket.